# User Location in Google Maps

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

I am trying a simple code to find out the user current location. However, I am unable to figure out why it is not working. I am not sure if this is related to a new set of standards imposed by google maps
here is the full Html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>User Location</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background: #EEE;
            font-family: sans-serif;
        }
        #TheMap {
            width: 100%;
            min-height: 500px;
            margin: 0 0 4% 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Find User Location in googel Maps </h1>
    <div id="TheMap"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Enter_your_key&sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var UserLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
            function initialize() {
                var mapOptions = {
                    center: UserLatLng,
                    zoom: 12
                };
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("TheMap"), mapOptions);
            };
        initialize();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you having issue getting "position" object populated? Also call initialize only when the entire page is loaded:
window.onload=initialize;

Comment: I Tried window.onload=initilize(); but did not help

Comment: Your position variable is undefined. Any errors in firebug output?

Comment: Any idea how to populate / define the position object?

Comment: see the answer with formatted code

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

  // put your initialization code here


});
```

Comment: Thank you , Although this has removed the error of having undefined position object. However, it is still not showing as I am getting a message saying " the following sites have been blocked from tracking your location ..etc". Although I already activated the option "Allow all sites to track my physical location".

Comment: That is expected, as the geo API follows user privacy settings. Maybe you could use some geo-ip resolution as a fallback default location?

Answer (score 0):

> The sensor parameter of the URL must be included, and indicates
>   whether this application uses a sensor (such as a GPS locator or HTML5
>   geolocation) to determine the user's location.

On your code, you have it set as **false**. It must be set as **true**:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=Enter_your_key&sensor=true"></script>
```